# What mode consists of the note G A Bb C Db E F G?

Tags: theory, scales, modes

I was playing random scales .
I came to a strange nice sounding mode,but could not find out what it's name theoretically.
(Even I could not find a tonic sounding in it)

The scale/mode notes are :

G A Bb C Db E F G

Does anybody know what is this mode ? 
And in what category we can put it ? 
Persian,greek,turkish,jazz, ...?

Comment: I'm not going to post links here, but do a google search for "scale finder". This tool will allow you tofind the scale that matches the notes you are playing, you can change options to allow the tool to find you scales that are not only western scales, but exotic scales and modes aswell.

Comment: For me the tonic-sounding as you call it is definitely DOMINANT because of the 7th C-Bb being the strongest interval. The also very strong three-half-tones between Db-E are rather for coloring but not for defining a tonic structure as seen by western eyes/ears. See my post below...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could consider as a scale derived from the F [harmonic major scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_major_scale) as the F harmonic major scale contains the notes:

> F G A Bb C Db E F

You can view this scales as just a major scale with a lowered 6th and this type of scale comes up in the *Lydian Chromatic Concept*.

Comment: I have a similar approach like @Dom above but there is one thing I do feel differently. See my post above/below...

Answer (score 6):

As pointed out by Dom, it is indeed the second mode of the (F) harmonic major scale. I would just like to add that this scale is often referred to as [Dorian b5](http://docs.solfege.org/3.21/C/scales/ham.html#II). Viewing this scale as a Dorian scale with one altered note makes it easy to remember its structure and to come up with appropriate fingerings.

Comment: For me the scales with **b5th** are a little problematic. **LOCRIAN** can be used over a **half-diminished** chord but that makes it worse because these chords do not define a clear tonality either (for us westerners). So the fact that such a precise and clear sounding, memorable scale like **DORIAN** that dominates a whole music culture (celtic/irish) should be polluted by a **flat 5th** really makes me feel uncomfortable. See my approach in my answer above/below...

Comment: @mramosch: Like it or not, but it *is* a dorian b5 scale. Note that the OP clearly indicated that G is the root. Of course you can discuss all 7 modes (and there are indeed names for them), but I referred to the original question with the root G, and that's a dorian b5 scale. You can give it another name, but the great advantage of the name "dorian b5" is that everybody (who knows what dorian is) immediately knows what you're talking about.

Comment: To @Matt: You are definitely right, I didn't contradict or argue about that. And I **do** like it... ;-)  But if it had been so obvious to Was.Francis  about DORIAN and DORIAN b5 he wouldn't have asked for help - so he definitely didn't know what you were talking about. And about clearly having indicated the root - I quote: "Even I could not find a tonic sounding in it"! This tells me he couldn't just figure what the root/base note/key of the scale was - he just randomly chose starting from G.

Comment: To @Matt: You are right - all traditional modes do have the same tonal material to their disposal, just different places of the half-tone-steps and thus a different characteristic interval. Like the dorian 6th that distinguishes it from a plain minor scale. That's why it is so important to take the root note under consideration to get a correct **FUNCTIONAL** structure. You assumed G to be the root, I assumed that the OP had no special root in mind. So no bad feelings... ;-)))

Comment: @mramosch: OK, but the root is in the ear of the listener, nowhere else. As you know, *any* of the 7 notes can be the root; so the question "what is the root" doesn't make much sense. What makes sense, and that's also how I understood the question, is what scale it is (if started on the G), or what mode of which basic scale it is (a mode of the harmonic major scale), and this has been answered appropriately, at least in my understanding.

Comment: You answered absolutely accurate! That's why I upvoted your answer. But I do not agree that the root is in the ear of the listener. It depends on which functional structure you put in your cadences. So e.g. the - lets call it DOMINANT functionality - which you achieve with a dom.7th chord in IONIAN setting would be a chord of the VII in DORIAN. -> I - VII - I instead of I - V - I... - And by that you are setting a functional environment that distinguishes every modal scale from the other - and the root is not in the ear of the listener. And I am speaking of the traditional use of modal scales.

Comment: Of course when it comes to Modal Jazz things are getting more liberate and unclear - where it is sometimes really impossible to make out any TONIC functional structure.

Comment: @mramosch: If you're just given 7 notes (as in the above question) then there's no reference to any harmonic context. And it is this situation which I referred to when I said "the root is in the ear of the listener". The OP didn't say "this is what I hear over a C7 chord". If that had been the case, the answer would obviously have been "mixolydian b9". After all it doesn't matter, it's a mode of harmonic major; just choose the appropriate mode/root for the given harmonic context.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar approach like @Dom but there is one thing I do feel very differently.

If it were a **major scale** in F - the pattern of the **5th, 6th, 7th, 8th** that has way more the taste of a **minor scale** wouldn't be so molesting to my western ears. In german this is also called '**harmonic major**' because it resembles both - the **major scale** and the **harmonic minor scale**.

For me a far better approach is to honor the presence of this **flat 7th** (**Bb**) as it is under the aspect of having a **C7** scale (**DOMINANT** function).

The **Db** gives an additional **eastern** flavor to it but it is still **DOMINANT**. A perfect scale to play over a **dominant-7th-chord** with the **additional tension b9** -> **C7/b9**. Some kind of **gipsy-dominant-7th** scale - or if you want **GIPSY-MINOR** :-) for the big picture.

And on top of everything the sound of this scale, because of being so **DOMINANT**, asks loudly for a resolution to a **TONICA**, that being **C7/b9 -> F/Fm**.

But I guess at the end of the day it is a matter of musical culture and what we are used to listen to. There are peoples that can harp over a dominant-7th chord all day long without having the urgent feeling of:

Where for Christ's sake is the **TONICA** (root) ???

This is almost like listening to Richard Wagner ;-)

Comment: I've reread this a few times and I still can't figure out what scale/mode you are saying the notes belong to which is what the user who asked the question wanted to know about.

Comment: Oh I think now you made it clearer for us,maybe it is tied with what musical culture you are more comfortable with. I have to tell you that I came from an eastern culture that has even quarter tones in it's scale but, trained my ear for western music and jazz , so I can feel comfortable with both claims about the tonic.

Comment: @tom I think he talk about why the tonic is hard to be felt

Comment: @mramosch in another approach for feeling the tonic : someone here has posted about tonal gravity, so here the claim says that the tonic changes while you are playing this scale which sounds interesting to research why this tonic gravity changes ! .

Comment: @Was.Francis: Lucky you, coming from a different culture and having the nerve and guts to go for something completely new. Respect!

Comment: PART 1: @Was.Francis: About the tonic gravity - well as you posted a scale without any reference where the scale actually begins or ends we have to make our own assumptions of where it begins or ends. Dom's approach was the F scale which is definitely valid. An assumption but valid. My assumption is that the 7th has more impact as a tonic indicator as the 3-half-steps which in my opinion add some strong color but not that much of a tonic indication. If you stressed the bass note strongly enough you can make it any color you like.

Comment: PART 2:  @Was.Francis: And of course tonic gravity changes as well with the edge notes of your scale. If you started the scale with F - beginning with the major part - the gravity will be very different as opposed to start with the C. Here you establish the GIPSY part first (color) and fix the impression with the flat 7th. So you get the perfect impression of a DOMINANT structure...

Comment: PART 3: @Was.Francis: So my very biased personal musical instinct tends to feel it as a **DOMINANT** structure. From C to C with a flat 7th and a GIPSY b9 leading to a three-half-step interval that brings additional color to the scale...

Comment: @Dom: Sorry, but I am not a native so I really don't know the correct term in english - but I guess Harmonic-Major  is quite adequate. Or if you want it in theoretical speech: MIXOLYDIAN with a flat 9th alteration. Hope that clarifies things. Sorry for not always finding the appropriate words...

Comment: Thank you :) I have to say It was hard long way to learn and  train my ear, but  in the end I benefited a lot from it and now I'm using it to add more colors to music and create fusions. Lastly I want to add that in eastern music this scale is called "Zanjaran Maqam" (مقام الزنجران) for anybody that is interested to read about it. Thanks for having this discussion with me :)

Comment: @Was.Francis: Thanks for the hint ;-) --- May I ask where you are actually from or do I disrespect your privacy by that? But maybe it would be helpful to all of us to learn to understand why people are asking certain questions and what their cultural background is...

Comment: Honestly I don't think it would be helpful to know where I'm from, I don't want to deviate from the topic, but for your Curiosity I'm an Arab and my hints are based on the Arab Cultural Music, you are invited to read and hear from it.